# Delete button doesn't show up on some of the tasks on the todo list

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I made a todo app, but you can't delete some of the items. I tried a lot of stuff, but it doesn't work. Can you help me understand the reason for the errors? I'm also trying to figure out a way to increase the character limit.

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By Zarif Sefat -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SideQuests | Simple Todo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="logo-or-something"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SideQuests</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>SIDE QUESTS</header>
    <div class="inputField">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add your new side quest">
      <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="todoList">
      <!-- data are comes from local storage -->
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> pending side quests</span>
      <button>Clear All</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
::selection{
  color: #ffff;
  background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68EACC 0%, #497BE8 100%);
}
.wrapper{
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 120px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper header{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.wrapper .inputField{
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
}
.inputField input{
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.inputField input:focus{
  border-color: #8E49E8;
}
.inputField button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 21px;
  outline: none;
  background: #8E49E8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.inputField button:hover,
.footer button:hover{
  background: #721ce3;
}
.inputField button.active{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.wrapper .todoList{
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.todoList li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.todoList li .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.todoList li:hover .icon{
  right: 0px;
}
.wrapper .footer{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.footer button{
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #8E49E8;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.footer button.active{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.logo-or-something {
  color: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
```

js:

```javascript
// getting all required elements
const inputBox = document.querySelector(".inputField input");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".inputField button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todoList");
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector(".footer button");

// onkeyup event
inputBox.onkeyup = ()=>{
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting user entered value
  if(userEnteredValue.trim() != 0){ //if the user value isn't only spaces
    addBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the add button
  }else{
    addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button
  }
}

showTasks(); //calling showTask function

addBtn.onclick = ()=>{ //when user click on plus icon button
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting input field value
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo"); //getting localstorage
  if(getLocalStorageData == null){ //if localstorage has no data
    listArray = []; //create a blank array
  }else{
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);  //transforming json string into a js object
  }
  listArray.push(userEnteredValue); //pushing or adding new value in array
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //transforming js object into a json string
  showTasks(); //calling showTask function
  addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button once the task added
}

function showTasks(){
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
  if(getLocalStorageData == null){
    listArray = [];
  }else{
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); 
  }
  const pendingTasksNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingTasks");
  pendingTasksNumb.textContent = listArray.length; //passing the array length in pendingtask
  if(listArray.length > 0){ //if array length is greater than 0
    deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the delete button
  }else{
    deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the delete button
  }
  let newLiTag = "";
  listArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    newLiTag += `<li>${element}<span class="icon" onclick="deleteTask(${index})"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></li>`;
  });
  todoList.innerHTML = newLiTag; //adding new li tag inside ul tag
  inputBox.value = ""; //once task added leave the input field blank
}

// delete task function
function deleteTask(index){
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
  listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);
  listArray.splice(index, 1); //delete or remove the li
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray));
  showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
}

// delete all tasks function
deleteAllBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  listArray = []; //empty the array
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //set the item in localstorage
  showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove this from your css:

```
.todoList li{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And you will enter a long input, you will see where the problem is. It's not that the button doesn't show up, but it's where it shows up.

When your div is too long, the button won't appear in the same line, but lower, causing you to not see it.

To solve this problem, you could add this (the overflow hidden was already there):

```
.todoList li{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Setting `hoverflow:hidden` won't allow you to scroll, but the entire text would still be there. The other two lines will make the css cut the text when there's no more space. And this will make your button appear in the right place.

Comment: so do I keep the overflow hidden?

Comment: nevermind :) I tested it, and it worked! thanks for explaining it very amazingly :) I've never had anyone in my life explain something better than you :)